# How to avoid double calculations within case statements of MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if it is possible to avoid a second equal calculation within a CASE statement of MySQL 5.7?

```
CASE  
  WHEN char_length(cat.DESCRIPTION) > 0 THEN char_length(cat.DESCRIPTION)
  ELSE ''
END AS D_LENGTH
```

The second char_length seems redundant to me and might be reducing query performance. Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: You can try `WHEN char_length(cat.DESCRIPTION) AS des_len > 0 THEN des_len` i'm not sure if it will work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to want to display empty string when the character length of the column be zero, you could try using a `TRIM` trick here:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM CHAR_LENGTH(cat.DESCRIPTION)) AS D_LENGTH
FROM yourTable cat;
```

This works because whenever the character length of the description be greater than zero, it would never have any leading zeroes.  When that length *is* actually zero, the call to `TRIM` above would just strip off the single zero, leaving behind an empty string.

Regarding your current approach, no, there isn't much you can do directly to avoid the double call to `CHAR_LENGTH`.  But, as shown above, there are ways out which completely avoid the duplication.

Comment: Nice one! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use intermediate user-defined variable:

```sql
CASE  
  WHEN (@tmp:=char_length(cat.DESCRIPTION)) > 0 
  THEN @tmp
  ELSE ''
  END AS D_LENGTH
```

On "clear" model (a table with one varchar column, data lengths 20-250, 1kk rows, no indices, the whole table is cached) it takes ~15% less time to execute on my system (5.11-5.32s against 5.97-6.23s).

The query produces a warning "1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'." - ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

First, the performance cost of evaluating any expression is much less than the cost of the rest of the query.  So don't bother with such optimization.

Second, to rise to the challenge:

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(CHAR_LENGTH('asdf'), 0), 'empty');
+---------------------------------------------------+
| COALESCE(NULLIF(CHAR_LENGTH('asdf'), 0), 'empty') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 4                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(CHAR_LENGTH(''), 0), 'empty');
+-----------------------------------------------+
| COALESCE(NULLIF(CHAR_LENGTH(''), 0), 'empty') |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| empty                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```